# PhpMailer - After migrating to VPS with HestiaCp it can't send emails

Tags: phpmailer

This is the context:

I had a shared hosting plan at Hostgator (firstly) and WebHostPython (lately)  (both cPanel)
PHP Mailer 5.2 worked just perfect

I migrated from shared hosting to VPS
From cPanel to HestiaCP

PHPMailer is unable to send emails

I made some variable declaration on the script, but it is still not working, even after trying to move from
PHP-Mailer 5.2 to 6.8

It seems that "clasically" the script took the smtp configuration directly from the cPanel config, or something like that, as an example

$mail->Host were not defined on the script that allways worked fine.

now I define all the smtp settings, and it still not working

I'd LOVE if you can take 1 or 2 minutres to review this script and post your suggestion:

### At line 226 the definition of HOST begins...

```
<?php session_start();
if($_SESSION['user'] && $_SESSION['role'] == 2){}
else{
    header("location:index.php");
}
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css"> </link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/table.css"> </link>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Envío Mail</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="menu">
    <?php include 'menu.php';?>
</div>


<?php
function armarAsunto($nombreCarpeta) {
    $partes = explode("-", $nombreCarpeta);
    
    if($partes[1] == '01') { $MES = 'ENE'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '02') { $MES = 'FEB'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '03') { $MES = 'MAR'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '04') { $MES = 'ABR'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '05') { $MES = 'MAY'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '06') { $MES = 'JUN'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '07') { $MES = 'JUL'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '08') { $MES = 'AGO'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '09') { $MES = 'SEP'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '10') { $MES = 'OCT'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '11') { $MES = 'NOV'; }
    elseif ($partes[1] == '12') { $MES = 'DIC'; }
    else {$MES = 'MES';};
    
    if($partes[2] == '01') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '1ra. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '02') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '2da. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '03') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '3ra. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '04') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '4ta. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '05') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '5ta. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '06') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '6ta. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '07') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '7ma. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '08') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '8va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '09') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '9na. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '10') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '10ma. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '11') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '11va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '12') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '12va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '13') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '13va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '14') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '14va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '15') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '15va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '16') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '16va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '17') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '17va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '18') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '18va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '19') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '19va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    elseif ($partes[2] == '20') { $textoNumeroActualizacion = '20va. Actualización de precios.'; }
    else {$textoNumeroActualizacion = 'Actualización de precios.';};    
    
    $asunto = $MES . "/" . $partes[0] . " - " . $textoNumeroActualizacion; 

    return $asunto;
}


/*Funcion para validar checkbox*/
function IsChecked($chkname,$value)
  {
      if(!empty($_POST[$chkname]))
      {
          foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval)
          {
              if($chkval == $value)
              {
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
;?>


</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

    <form id="envioMail" name="envioMail" action="#" method="post">
    <p>Adjuntar: <select class="Select-Actualizacion" id="archivosAdjuntos" name="archivosAdjuntos">
        <?php 
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        $ini_array = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
        //Cargo valores de configuración
        $host = $ini_array['host'];
        $dbuser = $ini_array['dbusercsv'];
        $dbpass = $ini_array['dbpasscsv'];
        $schema = $ini_array['schema'];
        $ruta_envio_mail = $ini_array['carpeta_ENVIO_MAIL'];
        $directorio = $ruta_envio_mail;
        $carpetas  = scandir($directorio,SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);

        print '<option value="Seleccionar">Seleccionar</option>';
        foreach ($carpetas as &$nombreCarpeta) {
            if($nombreCarpeta != "." && $nombreCarpeta != ".."){
                print '<option value="'.$nombreCarpeta.'">'.$nombreCarpeta.'</option>';
            }    
        }

        
        //JavaScript para cargar el Asunto
        print '<script type="text/javascript">';
        print '    var myData = new Array();';
        //Cargo los valores del asunto
        foreach ($carpetas as &$nombreCarpeta) {
            if($nombreCarpeta != "." && $nombreCarpeta != ".."){
                $asuntoFinal = armarAsunto($nombreCarpeta);
                print 'myData["'.$nombreCarpeta.'"] = "'. $asuntoFinal .'";';
            }    
        }       
        print '</script>';
        
        ?>
    </select>
    
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="enviomail" value="ENVIAR" />

    
    </p>
    
    <textarea id="asunto" name="asunto" rows="1" cols="80">Actualización de precios</textarea>
    
    </br>
    
    <textarea name="cuerpoMail" rows="12" cols="80">Cuerpo del mail</textarea>
    
    </br>
    

    

<?php
                  $con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $schema);
                  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                  }
                  mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                  mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
                  $sql = "select CONCAT(apellido,', ',nombre) NOMBRE, Nombre_libreria LIBRERIA, mail MAIL from users where role in (2,3)";
                  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                  
                  $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                  if($row_cnt > 0){
                      Print "<table class='rwd-table'>";
                      Print "<tr>";
                      Print "<th>Nombre</th>";
                      Print "<th>Libreria</th>";
                      Print "<th>Casilla de Mail</th>";
                      Print "<th><input type=\"checkbox\"  onclick=\"checkAll('listaCasillasEnvioMail[]');\" checked> Enviar</th>";
                      Print "<th><input type=\"checkbox\"  onclick=\"checkAll('adjuntoArchivos[]');\" checked> Adjuntar</th>";
                      Print "</tr>";
                  }
                  
                  
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    Print "<tr>";
                    Print '<td>' . $row['NOMBRE'] . "</td>";
                    Print '<td>' . $row['LIBRERIA'] . "</td>";
                    Print '<td>' . $row['MAIL'] . "</td>";
                    Print '<td> <input type="checkbox" name="listaCasillasEnvioMail[]" value="' . $row['MAIL'] . '" checked> </td>';
                    Print '<td> <input type="checkbox" name="adjuntoArchivos[]" value="' . $row['MAIL'] . '" checked> </td>';
                    Print "</tr>";
                  }
              
?>
    </form>
    
    

<?php



//Incluyo PHPMailer Project
// php Mailer Master (version 5.2) require_once('./PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');

// require_once('./PHPMailer6/src/PHPMailer.php');
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
require './PHPMailer6/src/PHPMailer.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['listaCasillasEnvioMail'])){
    

    $carpetaArchivos = $_POST['archivosAdjuntos'];


    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $schema);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    
    foreach($_POST['listaCasillasEnvioMail'] as $casillaEnvioMail) {

        $email = new PHPMailer();
    
        mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
        $sql = "select tab.casilla from (";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_1 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_2 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_3 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_4 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_5 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_6 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_7 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_8 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_9 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "' union all";
        $sql = $sql. " select mail_aux_10 casilla from users where mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "'";
        $sql = $sql. " ) tab where tab.casilla is not null and tab.casilla != '' ";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $email->AddCC($row['casilla']);
        }
                  
        // bloque agregado por la falla de HestiaCP que no reconoce la configuracion de email, o no se la traslada a/de PHP
        $email->isSMTP();
        $email->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $email->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $email->SMTPSecure       = false;
        $email->SMTPAutoTLS      = false;
        $email->Host             = 'my vps smtp' ;
        $email->Port             = 25; //use port 465 when using SMPTSecure = 'ssl'
        $email->SMTPAuth         = true;
        $email->Username         = 'user@example.com';
        $email->Password         = 'xxx';       
        $email->From             = 'user@example.com';
        $email->ConfirmReadingTo = 'user@example.com';
        $email->FromName         = 'Precios de Libros';
        $email->Subject          = $_POST['asunto'];
        $email->Body             = $_POST['cuerpoMail'];
        
        //$email->IsHTML(true);
        $email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $email->AddAddress( $casillaEnvioMail );

        
        if(IsChecked('adjuntoArchivos',$casillaEnvioMail))
            {
                //Valido que tipo de archivos tengo que enviar
                $sql = "select upper(ae.nombre_archivo) nombre_archivo from users user, tipo_archivos_envio tae, archivo_envio ae";
                $sql = $sql. " where user.tipo_archivos_envio_id = tae.id";
                $sql = $sql. " and tae.codigo_envio = ae.codigo_tipo_archivos_archivo";
                $sql = $sql. " and user.mail = '" . $casillaEnvioMail . "'";

                $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    //Cargo los archivos adjuntos
                    $archivos  = scandir($ruta_envio_mail."/".$carpetaArchivos);
                    foreach ($archivos as &$nombreArchivo) {
                        $existe = stripos($nombreArchivo, $row['nombre_archivo']);
                        if($nombreArchivo != "." && $nombreArchivo != ".." && $existe !== false){
                            $email->AddAttachment( $ruta_envio_mail. "/" .$carpetaArchivos . "/" . $nombreArchivo );
                            print "<p>SE ADJUNTARA EL ARCHIVO: " . $nombreArchivo . "</p>";
                        }    
                    }   
                }

            }
            else{
                    print '<p>NO adjunto los archivos para ' . $casillaEnvioMail . '</p>';
                }

        

        //Envìo el mail
        if(!$email->Send()) {
            print '<p>No se pudo enviar el mail a la casilla de "' . $casillaEnvioMail . '"';
            print " --> <b>Detalle del error:</b> " . $email->ErrorInfo . "</p>";
        } else {
            print "<p>Se envió el mail a la casilla de: " . $casillaEnvioMail . "</p>";
        }       
    }
}
?>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.envioMail.archivosAdjuntos.onchange = updateText;

    function updateText() {
      var obj_sel = document.envioMail.archivosAdjuntos;
      document.envioMail.asunto.value = myData[obj_sel.value];
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll(checkName){
        var inputs = document.getElementsByName(checkName);
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
            if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" ) { 
                if(inputs[i].checked == true) {
                    inputs[i].checked = false ;
                } else if (inputs[i].checked == false ) {
                    inputs[i].checked = true ;
                }
            }  
        }  
    }
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are many reason why mail won't arrive, most not related to your code. Work through the answers to the linked question and make sure you've addressed every one before coming back for more help.

Comment: As always, the first place you should look is [the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). It's likely your new hosting provider blocks outbound SMTP. If you didn't have `Host` set before, you were probably using the default `mail()` function sending mechanism.

Comment: @Synchro Do you freelance by any mean? the smtp is working, I can send using Outlook (from the office package) at the same smtp service

Comment: Running Outlook locally is not the same as connecting from your server, and it's where you connect from that makes the difference. Your local connection may not limit SMTP connections but your server might.

Comment: The thing is that no error is being logged. I even created a new script, that JUST send a dummy email (fix, by code) and it doesn't work, and doesn't log or report to the screen any error (both php or mail server). Do you know the linux command to watch the SMTP server activity to see if something reaches the service?